# Evaluate $\int \frac{1}{ax^2-bx}\,dx$ with substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

Evaluate $\int\frac{1}{ax^2-bx}\,dx$

First try:

$$\int\frac{1}{ax^2-bx}\,dx = \int\frac{1}{bx^2(\frac{a}{b}-\frac{1}{x})}\,dx$$

By substituting $u=\frac{a}{b}-\frac{1}{x}$ so $du=\frac{1}{x^2}\,dx$ we have,

$$\int\frac{1}{bx^2(\frac{a}{b}-\frac{1}{x})} \, dx = \frac{1}{b} \int\frac{1}{u} \, du = \frac{\ln|u|}{b}+C = \frac{\ln|\frac{a}{b}-\frac{1}{x}|}{b}+C=\frac{\ln|\frac{ax-b}{bx}|}{b}+C$$

Second try:

$$\int\frac{1}{ax^2-bx} \, dx = \frac{1}{b}\int\frac{b}{x^2(a-\frac{b}{x})} \, dx$$

By substituting $u=a-\frac{b}{x}$ so $du=\frac{b}{x^2}dx$ we have,

$$\frac{1}{b}\int\frac{b}{x^2(a-\frac{b}{x})}dx = \frac{1}{b}\int\frac{1}{u}\,du = \frac{\ln|u|}{b}+C = \frac{\ln|a-\frac{b}{x}|}{b}+C=\frac{\ln|\frac{ax-b}{x}|}{b} + C$$

It seems to me that $\frac{\ln|\frac{ax-b}{bx}|}{b}+C\neq\frac{\ln|\frac{ax-b}{x}|}{b}+C$, so, whats the matter ?!

Comment: Similar funny example: $\int \sin x \cos x \ \mathrm dx$. You can try $u=\sin x$ or $u=\cos x$, which seem to give different results, but they're the same actually.

Comment: $$\frac{\ln \left| \frac{ax-b}{bx} \right|} b = \frac{\ln\left|\frac{ax-b} x\right|}{b}+\text{constant}$$ What would cause you to conclude that these are not equal? How much work did you put into trying to find out whether they are equal? (In fact, they are.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that

$$\frac{\ln|\frac{ax-b}{bx}|}{b}+C=\frac{\ln|\frac{ax-b}{x}|}{b} + \frac{\ln |\frac{1}{b}|}{b} + C=\frac{\ln|\frac{ax-b}{x}|}{b}+C_2$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1}{b}\ln\left|\frac{ax-b}{bx}\right|=\frac{1}{b}\left(\ln\left|\frac{ax-b}{x}\right|-\ln|b|\right)=\frac{1}{b}\ln\left|\frac{ax-b}{x}\right|+\frac{1}{b}\ln|b|$$
And $\frac{\ln|b|}{b}$ is just a constant.

The primitive function is not just a function - it's a set of functions:
$$\int f :=\{g\mid g'=f\}$$
And we usually denote this set as one of its element + a constant. So, for example, we can say that $\int x = \frac{x^2}{2}+C$, or $\int x = \frac{x^2}{2}+2-e^\pi+C$, they denote the same set.

Note: Our calculus teacher was not using the $+C$. You can also leave it out, but it might cause some problem later, for example, when you will deal with differential equations.

Comment: Just to clarify that constant is negligible since the "C" absorbs it.

Comment: I see, so they are actually equivalent. Thank you!

Comment: @Sorfosh Yes, that's one way to explain it. I added a bit different explanation.

Comment: @giannisl9 Yes. I added a bit more of explanation and a note, it might help you a bit more.